# How to pass url to webview from rss reader

Tags: java, android, eclipse, rss

I have created a simple rss reader from this tutorial, http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2010/08/android-rss-reader-tutorial.html

This shows a list of current rss feeds, but how can I make this clickable so that when you select a feed it opens in a webview, I know how to setup the webview the problem I am having is how to grab the url from the rss and where to put the code.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent message = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                          Uri.parse(urvariable.get(position)));
                       startActivity(message);
            }
```